# How to change the number of partitions using coalesce?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I'm using spark with java and Cassandra data base, and in my program i've used `mapPartitions` to request cassadra. But i've noticed that my `mapPartitions` is executed in only one spark node. In order to see the number of partitions in my RDD, i used :

```
System.out.println(MyRDD.partitions().size());
```

And it display 1 partition. 
I've found that i can edit the number of partition usig this :

```
JavaRDD MyRDD2= MyRDD.coalesce(8, false);
```

But it doesn't work and my partition number still 1.

Can you help me please to change the number of partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set shuffle to true in order to coalesce to a larger number of partitions:

```
JavaRDD MyRDD2= MyRDD.coalesce(8, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As per coalesce() function of RDD, we can reduce the number of partition. For increasing partition number repartition() function should use.

var textRDD = scontext.textFile("file:///home/rajeev/Test.scala", 3);

    print("================== "+textRDD.getNumPartitions);

   var newRDD = textRDD.coalesce(6, false);
print("==================:: "+newRDD.getNumPartitions+"\n");

   var newRDD1 = textRDD.coalesce(6, true);
print("==================:: "+newRDD1.getNumPartitions+"\n");

Output is 3 and 3 and 6 respective print statement.

Ideally it should not be happen. Please could you explain. Is it because we are shuffling data.
```